# Android Admobs not displaying banner ads after adoption for google Designed for Family Program

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

As suggested by google play store I have made android application to opt in for Primarily Child-Directed and Designed for Families programs. Since its once approved the Admobs has stopped displaying banner ads. Does any know about why ads is not displaying and does i need to make any changes in my code to display ads by using admob sdk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your logs for errors and update in your question

Comment: It shows Failed to load ads : Error - 3

Comment: no fill (  ads not available ). If you are using custom settings for ads then try to update them to see if that gives any ads. If you are using default ad settings use a ad meditation

Comment: does admobs has any support link for directly writing  to them ?

Comment: it's not admob issue. They don't have enough ads to show ads for your id and scenario, you should always use ad meditation to fill ads in such cases. You can write to them via contactus on top right of admob console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your admob banner

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431?hl=en

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
        .build();
```

Comment: I have tried to put this code but still its not displaying ads.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and it was the number of family (<5 years) ads is very small so I change my app to (>13) and it works .